# Set Deployment Info and Build Phases by script in iOS project

Tags: xcode, fuse

In order to automize the build process when using a cross platform framework (FUSE). Unless I am wrong, I coudn't find any settings in FUSE to cover this cases so that's why I am trying to set them after FUSE builds and generates the xcode project files.

One of the issues I am facing right now is about the target device and the other one is adding an entry in the build phases.

**STEP BY STEP**

1. FUSE build generates the xcode project files including a new xcodeproj file everytime with a different FUSE-XCODE classes mapping so I cannot reuse it from one build to another
2. I can open the project in xcode IDE
3. Do some settings manually (target device and add a bundle resource)
4. Generate a build
5. Publish it to TestFlight

However, I am trying to make a command line build with the following steps:

1. FUSE build generates the xcode project files including a new xcodeproj file everytime with a different FUSE-XCODE classes mapping so I cannot reuse it from one build to another
2. Set the target device and the bundle resorce path by script
3. Build by xcode command line tools and generate the IPA file
4. Publish it to TestFlight

I already achieved to writhe the app name, version and build number by PlistBuddy using an script. However I didn't manage to do the same for the target device and adding a bundle resource.

About the device, I wanna set iPhone only:

[image]

About the Build Phases, I wanna add a Bundle Resource with the license of one library we use in the project. The license file is in a path belonging to the project.

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  How does the license relate to FUSE?  Why can't you set the deployment device once-and-for-all (why does it need a Build Phase)?

Comment: @trojanfoe I updated the explanation. The xcodeproj changes in each build so any settings made in the Xcode IDE will be lost everytime. The license I mention doesn't relate to FUSE as is, it is a third party library we use in and it needs the activation file present in the phone to work. I hope everything is clearer now.

Comment: Yes that makes alot more sense.  `PlistBuddy` can certainly change the Device as that's defined in the `Info.plist` file but it won't help with the Build Phases part.

Comment: @trojanfoe may you help me with the key name I have to use to set that value? I took a look into the Info.plist and I didn't found the right field to set it.

Comment: Looks I might be wrong about it being in the `Info.plist` file then as I cannot see that either :-|